# change template with button

Tags: themes, customization

I created plugin with code :

```
function fxn($theme) {

if(isset($_POST['zmien'])){
    $theme = 'loose';}
else{
    $theme = 'twentytwenty';}

return $theme;
}

add_filter('template', 'fxn');
add_filter('option_template', 'fxn');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'fxn');
```

I found the code and adapted it to my website.
I have created the plugin and it works only partially. When I click the button the template changes but when I click on any element on the new template the page returns to the previous template.

How can I make a change of template active until the end of browsing the page?

Comment: What are you trying to implement? Is it a theme switcher in the admin area? A demo preview? Different solutions may be applicable depending on what you're trying to build, any context you can add would be super helpful

Comment: The code provided in my answer would work for a single user browsing the site, how then wants to change the theme.  If you are trying to do something else you will have to explain more, as Tom J Nowell mentioned above.

Comment: I must have two versions of the site. One ordinary, the other in a completely simplified version for people with restrictions. I thought that there would be a switch from the basic template to the latter and that it would be available for the user of the page.
And this solution is only appropriate in this situation.
None of the existing plugins do not.

Comment: You can make a minimal version of your site with just CSS, you can do a lot with it.  This will be the recommend approach rather than switching the theme.

Comment: so make a second css for the template and customize it to a minimum?
But how to load it later so that it changes?

Comment: If your _actual_ problem is "I must have two versions of the site. One ordinary, the other in a completely simplified version for people with restrictions.", then this is completely the wrong approach. You should ask the question you actually need answered, otherwise you're getting help with a solution that will never solve your actual problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no solutions in the form of plugins that would comprehensively address disability issues.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I said...

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you talking about? . I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [switch_theme()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme).

`<?php switch_theme( $stylesheet ) ?>`

I have personally never used it but it sounds like what you want.  You just need to pass the stylesheet name you are using.

Here is a very basic demo I put together.  You would basically but the following code, where ever its needed in both themes.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="theme" value="theme1">
    <label for="theme1">Theme1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="theme" value="theme2">
    <label for="theme2">Theme2</label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    $radioVal = $_POST["theme"];

    if($radioVal == "theme1"){
        switch_theme('gemcore-ui');
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    else if ($radioVal == "theme2"){
        switch_theme('testtheme');
    }
?>
```

I tested this and it worked well but I needed to refresh the page afterwards, so I added the header("Refresh:0").  Also you can add as many radio options as needed.

Comment: This is only half the answer due to a logic bug in the original code, but it is on the right track. The only issue is that this would change the theme for everybody, which would be undesirable if the OP is trying to implement a preview feature for a demo site. The OP will need to clarify what they are trying to build with this

Comment: I was able to test this works by creating 2 themes and adding it into 1 when needed.  Just got to be careful not to have theme in both themes at the same time with no logic :)

Comment: I updated the answer, it should be a pretty complete solution now.

Comment: That won't work for multiple users, it works like a theme switcher, but if the goal is to allow previewing of themes on a per user basis then this will break that if a second user tries to use it. Also, the call to `header` will generate a PHP notice that the headers have already been sent

Comment: I took it as changing the template for a single user browser the site.

Comment: I must have two versions of the site. One ordinary, the other in a completely simplified version for people with restrictions. I thought that there would be a switch from the basic template to the latter and that it would be available for the user of the page.
And this solution is only appropriate in this situation.
None of the existing plugins do not.

Comment: thank you,RiddleMeThis . I will test your idea

Comment: the problem is that when I change the template I do it pre-emptively. When someone else enters the page, he also sees the name of the last user.
How to do it so that a good template always opens a basic template?. In the backroom after switching the active theme becomes switched.